# add_theme_support( 'custom-header' ) does not add option menu in dashboard

Tags: theme-development, themes, add-theme-support, custom-header

I'm writing a new theme from scratch, based off the Toolbox theme. My installation of WP is straight out of the box. I added add_theme_support('custom-header'); to my functions.php file, but the "header" options screen does not appear in the dashboard. I can see it if I visit the site, in the toolbar at the top, but not in the dashboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told that `add_theme_support('custom-header');` is not supposed to work as I expected yet. See the full answer I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148832/wordpress-add-theme-support-custom-header-does-not-add-option-to-dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

From Codex:

> If attached to a hook, it must be after_setup_theme. The init hook may
>   be too late for some features.

Try this

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_setup' ) ):
    function mytheme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup' );
```

If you use Toolbox Theme, find in functions.php

```
function toolbox_setup() {
```

and add inside this function

```
add_theme_support('custom-header');
```

Links - [Add Theme Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support), [Custom Headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers)